# cakephp form input with no name attribute

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am using CakePHP 2.2.4.

I am using the Form Helper to create a form. I need to have a form input with no name attribute.

Is this possible with the formhelper or should I just use HTML for creating this form?

eg in HTML:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number stripe-sensitive required" />
```

Basically Am I able to do the above using the formhelper in CakePHP ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can overrule any property in the `$options` array, which is the second argument to the `input()` method. So technically you could do:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model.field', array(
    'label' => false,
    'div' => false,
    'name' => false,
    'maxlength' => 20,
    'autocomplete' => 'off',
    'class' => 'card-number stripe-sensitive'
));
```

But please be aware the dropping the `name` attribute makes the entire field useless if you want to do anything with it's data in your controller/model, as the `$this->data` array gets it's names from the name attribute of your input fields.

Comment: @bfavaretto this will not add a wrapping div since 'div' is set to false.

Comment: @BorislavSabev I said that before Oldskool added that to the answer.

Comment: @bfavaretto ok, ok. No hard feelings man. Just clarifying for the other guy that's going to look at this in the future. ;)

Comment: @BorislavSabev No problem! I removed that comment to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP needs the name attribute to be able to know what is being submitted by the form. I'm not sure I follow why you would want there to be no name attribute.

If you are concerned that a named input will be passing something to a save method you could always use [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) in your controller to remove it from $this->request->data before saving/validation.

Otherwise, you can manually add the markup to your view, but again not sure why you would want an unnamed input element.

Comment: Reason I need an unnamed input element is I am using stripe.com for taking online credit card payments using their stripe.js for PCI compliance. For this they require the form you use to collect credit card information to have no input name.

Comment: The input name is only needed to *read* regular form submissions. It can be perfectly optional in any other scenario: read-only display, JavaScript manipulation, AJAX submissions, third-party processing...